# Search indexer for NoSql, specifically Cassandra

Tags: solr, nosql, cassandra, sphinx, elasticsearch

I'm looking to integrate a Cassandra implementation with a search indexing solution. Some of the options I've come across are Sphinx, Solr (Solandra), Elastic Search.

I'll need to support heavy read write operations. I currently use Solr which works well for heavy reads but not so well when combined with heavy writes.

I need to support a variety of queries like full text, wildcard, range etc.

Would appreciate any pointers on what the best way to go might be. A product that has good integration with Cassandra and will support heavy read write operations is really what would be ideal.

Comment: You may be interested in DataStax Enterprise which does exactly this. It integrates Solr with Cassandra to provide indexing/searching of data inserted into Cassandra. Note: I work for DataStax. http://www.datastax.com/products/enterprise

Answer (score 1):

ElasticSearch is a fine candidate.  Writes, like reads, are distributed horizontally and seamlessly across shards.  Functionality-wise, it's a superset of Solr.  I'm not yet aware of anything that ES hasn't supported or improved from Solr.  ES is also much more mature than the late efforts to distribute Solr.

ES doesn't integrate with Cassandra directly, but you could easily write code to index data.  If you're proficient in Java, you could turn it into a [River](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2010/09/28/the_river.html).

You might also consider using ES as a key/value store itself instead of Cassandra.  They're both dynamo-like, but ES is much better at retrieving data.